# how to add :before css conditionally react

Tags: reactjs

i want to conditionally add :before css selector to my dynamic product, currently its mutual fund but it can be later in future, please let me know how to do it

```
        <div  className={`${style.right_block}`}>
          <ul  className={`${style.three_points}`}>
            <li  className={`${style.mutual_fund}`} >{current_web.cat}</li>
            <li  className={`${style.beginner_icon}`}>{current_web.difficulty}</li>
            <li  className={`${style.time_icon}`}>{current_web.dur}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

as you can see my product, difficulty, and dur(duration ) coming from api,
i want to chnage product :before icon based on my product,

Comment: you can use style prop and give your condition there

Comment: You can add your :before to a given classname inside a css file and only add that classname to an element conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to conditionally add a :before css rule to a certain element?

```
<div  className={`${style.right_block}`}>
      <ul  className={`${style.three_points}`}>
        <li  className={(yourCondition ? style.nameOfStyleInCssFileWithBeforeRule : style.normalStyle)} >{current_web.cat}</li>
        <li  className={`${style.beginner_icon}`}>{current_web.difficulty}</li>
        <li  className={`${style.time_icon}`}>{current_web.dur}</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `useState`:

```
const [ConditinClass , setConditinClass] = useState(styles.NoBeforeStateMent);
```

Then to style your component :

```
        <div className={ConditinClass} >
        ... your stuff
        </div>
```

And to switch to class with before :

```
setConditinClass(styles.classWithBefore)
```

Be sure to create both classes.